# Date and Html value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm New to JavaScript, I wrote a code to work out "age" by calculating date of birth and today's date. The function is working if I run it in the console, but how do I receive values from Input and pass it as parameters ?

I have tried to use .value but seems am doing the wrong thing.

```
var button = document.querySelector("#Button")

button.addEventListener("click", function(){


function calculate_age()

{

    var ourDay = document.querySelector("#input").value

  today_date = new Date();

    today_year = today_date.getFullYear();

    today_month = today_date.getMonth();

    today_day = today_date.getDate();

    age = today_year - ourDay;

    enter code here
    if ( today_month < (birth_month - 1))
    {
        age--;
    }
    if (((birth_month - 1) == today_month) && (today_day < birth_day))
    {
        age--;
    }
    return age;

}




})
```

Comment: You defined a function, but you never actually called it

Comment: as SLaks said you are just defining a function but not using it. change it to button.addEventListener("click", calculate_age);

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have an input field to ask the user for the year and the month of born.
Then you have to call a function and pass the input to the function. In JavaScript do not forget";". I assumed that by 'ourDay' you mean Year of the birth so I called it ourYear.
In the end, it will show the age.

```js
function calculate_age(){
  
    var ourYear = document.querySelector("#year").value;
    var birth_month = document.querySelector("#month").value;
 
    today_date = new Date();

    today_year = today_date.getFullYear();

    today_month = today_date.getMonth();

    today_day = today_date.getDate();

    age = today_year - ourYear;

     
    if ( today_month < (birth_month - 1))
    {
        age--;
    }
    if (((birth_month - 1) == today_month) && (today_day < birth_day))
    {
        age--;
    }
 alert(age);
    return age;

}
```

```html
<button id="Button" onclick="calculate_age()">Try it</button>
<input id="year" type="number" >
<input id="month" type="number">
```

Comment: Its  possible to to call the function inside the  addEventlistener("click",function()){}. Also , its possible to have <button id="Button" >Try it</button>
<input id="year" type="date" >
instead of<input id="year" type="number" >
<input id="month" type="number">(This is showing some error)